# Defining holomorphic function as an integral in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $U$ be a bounded connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f:\mathbb{C} \times U \to \mathbb{C}$ such that

1) for all $(u_1,\ldots,u_n) \in U$ the function $z \mapsto f(z,u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ is holomorphic

2) for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ the function
$(u_1,\ldots,u_n) \mapsto f(z,u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ is continuous

Can we conclude 
$F(z) = \int_U f(z,u_1,\ldots,u_n) \;du_1 \cdots du_n$
is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is NO! The function
$$
f:\mathbb{C}\times(0,1) \to \mathbb{C},\ f(z,u)=\exp\left(\frac{z}{u}\right)
$$
satisfies all the conditions. However the function $(0,1) \to \mathbb{C}, z \mapsto f(z,u)$ is not integrable. In particular the function $F: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C},\ F(z)=\int_0^1f(z,u)\,du$ is not well defined, and therefore it cannot be holomorphic.

Comment: what if for every $z$ the function $(u_1,...,u_n) \mapsto f(z,u_1,...,u_n)$ is bounded ?

Comment: The answer is still NO! Take the function $f:\mathbb{C}\times(0,1) \to \mathbb{C},\ f(z,u)=g(z)\sin(1/u)$ where $g: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic.

Comment: If $U$ is compact and 2) is replaced by function $f$ is continuous on the whole product set $\mathbb C\times U$, then the conclusion holds.